# Change CSS flex direction

Tags: css, flexbox

Is it possible to change the flex direction of blocks from one block to another?

I have a column of blocks (running vertically, obviously) using flex, but in the middle block, of these blocks, there are three smaller inner-blocks that need to run horizontally - and I've tried `display: inline-block`, and setting their parent to `display: flex; flex-direction: row`. I've tried setting them to `flex: 0` and `flex: none`, but they still display in a column.

So imagine this structure:

```
 0.body
   ->>1.overall container (has `display: flex; flex-direction: column`)
     ->>2.a label block (vertical, has fixed height)
     ->>2.a label block (vertical, has fixed height)
     ->>2.the container block (vertical, has `flex: 1`)
        ->>3.inner-block one (should be horizontal)
        ->>3.inner-block two (should be horizontal)
        ->>3.inner-block third (should be horizontal)
     ->>2.a label block (vertical, has fixed height)
     ->>2.a label block (vertical, has fixed height)
```

How do I make their parents display vertically and fill the vertical available space, while these three inner-blocks display horizontally with editable widths?

Answer (score 0):

I imagined the structure and here's what you can do:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container > .label {
  width: 100%;
}
.main > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="label">label1</div>
  <div class="label">label2</div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="inner-one">inner-one</div>
    <div class="inner-two">inner-two</div>
    <div class="inner-three">inner-three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="label">label3</div>
  <div class="label">label4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to achieve the same with all the divs on the same level ?